# Optional fields when matching log file rows using regex

Tags: regex, hadoop, logging, hive, hive-serde

I'm trying to parse a web log with regular expressions using [RegexSerDe](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.html). It works by matching each regex group with a column in a table and if the regex group is empty it assigns a null to that column.

I'm having trouble matching log rows with missing fields. There are two kinds of rows in this log:

```
<134>2016-10-23T23:59:59Z cache-iad2134 fastly[502801]: 52.55.94.131 "-" "-" Sun, 23 Oct 2016 23:59:59 GMT GET /apps/events/2016/10/11/3062653/?REC_ID=3062653&id=0 200

<134>2016-10-23T23:59:59Z cache-dfw1835 fastly[502801]: 1477267199
```

I wrote the below regex that matches the first type of row with all fields:

```
^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) "(\\S+)" "(\\S+)" (.*) (\\d{3})
```

But I played around with `?` to get the regex to optionally ignore the fields after the first 4 but kept messing up the columns.

Any suggestions on how I should add the `?` without changing the number of groups (so that the deserializer doesn't cough up)? Or any other way to do this you would suggest?

Comment: Since you haven't shown the regexp with the optional modifiers, how are we supposed to tell you what you did wrong? The only thing I can think of is that you forgot to make the spaces between the fields optional as well.

Answer (score 1):

Put a non-capturing group around all the fields after the first 4, and make it optional.

```
^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+)(?: "(\\S+)" "(\\S+)" (.*) (\\d{3}))?
```

Putting `?:` at the beginning of a group makes it non-capturing. So this group doesn't affect the number of groups that are captured.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar. That worked like a charm. I really appreciate your help.